# JSON stringify circular structure error

Tags: jquery, json

In the below code, for each staff member I am trying to grab a list of the group_ids of groups they supervise and then I want to stringify the array containing those ids and send it off to update the database.

However, when I try to stringify the mapped array, I get an error about converting a circular structure. I don't quite see what is circular in the below code.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
$(".staff_member").each(function() {
        var staff_id = $(this).attr("staff_id");

        var newarr = $(this).find(".staff_groups .staff_group").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("group_id");
        });
        alert(JSON.stringify(newarr));
        $.post(
            "staff_update.php",
            { staff_id: staff_id, groups: newarr },
            function(data) {
                var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                if(response.code == "success") {
                    alert("Done!");
                } else if(response.code == "failure") {
                    alert("Failure!");
                }
            }
        );
    });
```

Comment: Did you really mean to comment out that block of code in the middle?

Comment: Log in the console the content of newarr before stringify, maybe with this you see the circular reference.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't the problem I was having, but I updated the code

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the expanded object from calling `console.log(newarr)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert that to an array first .. `.map()` returns a **jQuery Object**

```
var newarr = $(this).find(".staff_groups .staff_group").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("group_id");
        }).get() ;
```

Comment: @jrubins .. Glad to have helped :)